# Java while ( keyispressed )

Tags: java, keypress

How do I write a code that loops while the LEFT or RIGHT arrow key is pressed?

Comment: What technologies are you using? Swing? JOGL? What?

Comment: it is a swing label component i wish to move to the left or right on keypress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a KeyListener to your swing component (assuming you're using swing), and mark the keyDown and keyUp event. Specifically, on keyDown set a boolean for movingLeft, and on keyUp unset the boolean.

A better solution might be to use a map of enumerations of directions to booleans, to make the code cleaner.

Example:

```
Map<MoveDirection, Boolean> moveMap = new HashMap<MoveDirection,Boolean>();
moveMap.put( MoveDirection.LEFT, false );
moveMap.put( MoveDirection.RIGHT, false );
moveMap.put( MoveDirection.UP, false );
moveMap.put( MoveDirection.DOWN, false );
```

Then `put` and `get` as necessary.

Comment: Well, if the app has a separate thread it can check the boolean, but if doesn't it has to create one (`new Thread() { public void run() { 
/* whatever */ } }.start();`) and that thread check the boolean flag (or something).

Comment: I assume he's running on the event dispatching thread. The complexity of the question (or lack thereof), lead me to assume EDT + Swing as the environment.

Comment: Note that the swing component has to have focus to receive keylistener events. For that reason, you may want to attach the keylistener to your JPanel (or JFrame)